# Cannot retrieve Mobile Number in Search API

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-schema

Hi i tried to create new field called **Mobile** managed property and mapped it to **Mobile,People:Mobile,ows_Mobile** crawled property connected to AD

```
https://siteURI.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27accountname:%22*firstname.lastname*%22%27&sourceid=%27B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31%27&selectProperties=%27PreferredName,Path,WorkEmail,PictureURL,JobTitle,Department,Mobile,WorkEmail,AboutMe,Office,Manager
```

[image]

However, it returns null. Maybe i am missing something.

[image]

Appreciated your help, thanks!

Comment: Have you run a full crawl? If not that's try that :)

Comment: Hi Morten, is the mapping correct?

Comment: They seem correvct yes :)